# How can i make two game objects are pass through each other in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made two game objects, player and enemy.
I hope two game objects collision detect and they are pass through each other.
Thus i put a check mark objects collider's 'is Trigger' and objects's 'rigid body'. So, i expected that objects are pass through each other.
But, player and enemy crashed each other. Why player and enemy crash?

i want two objects pass through each other.
help me please.

Comment: no one can answer your question unless you provide some example code - it's too vague

Answer (score 1):

A collider marked as a trigger should not cause physical collisions with an incoming Rigidbody ([see here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html)). Check and see if one of the player or any objects has a child with a collider that is not marked as a trigger.

Also note that a CharacterController component will be constrained by collisions, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html). CharacterControllers do not have a trigger option, so you will have to disable collisions through a different method. The most common methods are using `Physics.IgnoreCollision` or changing the layers of the objects and disabling collisions between layers in Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics. See here for more details: [Layer-based collision detection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) and [How to Ignore Collision between Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396091/how-to-ignore-collision-between-objects).

Comment: I checked child's trigger option but it was marked well. And
my question means collision of two game objects(player and enemy) have to caused. And the collision work successful. Now, they have to pass through each other at scene. But they are blocked by each other so they cant move anymore. In this situation, what can i do for solving this problem?